# Using Fraction in java

Tags: java

I feel like an idiot but why or how do I use Fraction objects in Java? I simply need to use [this class](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/teaching/docs/type/api/type/lib/Fraction.html).

I'm literally just going into an empty main() method, and writing

```
Fraction frac;
```

Then hitting Ctrl-shift-o to import anything necessary (nothing imports) and I get a "cant resolve to type" static error.

Tell me why I'm being stupid but then please let me know if/how I can use this class.

Comment: You need the `jar` that includes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [JAR File](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/teaching/resources/type/type.jar) that contains the class to your classpath

Answer (score 1):

The `Fraction` class you're trying to import is not part of Java SE. You need to include the jar which contains this class to the classpath of your project.